# What tool can i use to simulate users visiting my cloud based website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm looking for a tool where I can specify a request like "2k users visiting website [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with 4 users every 10 sec within 1 hour"

I'm learning AWS cloud and want to see how my auto scaling group works in response to burst of visitors.

Steady increase in traffic or burst of visitors coming in short timeframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct jargon for that is *”load testing”*.

And while specific product recommendation requests are considered off topic on this Q&A site the Wikipedia article lists a number of industry standard tools that may in one form or another be useful to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing

Comment: yes, thx u  - i just learned the correct term from another website lol..